# Synchronizing two large-ish (80m+ records) databases on a daily basis

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this, but couldn't find a better one. Also apologize because I'm new to the professional field and may not know the "terms-of-art"

We have a third-party-provided Oracle database we have been using for a few years that has most of our person-level data (names, ages, addresses, etc...) and we are trying to "synchronize" that database with a new one we are implementing. This doesn't have to be real-time, but our current plan is to create daily snapshots of the tables we need (about 80m records in total, most tables are under 500k), then output those records and import them on the other end.

Everything AFTER we get the records works fine through our pipeline, but our problem is that the Oracle DB is fairly outdated (the DBAs are not interested in upgrading their service), so the outputs are overloading their system (CPU and IO) and waiting for all outputs would make this process be a few hours long.

The SQL that generates these outputs is just:

`CREATE TABLE x NOLOGGING AS (SELECT * FROM table);
commit;`

Then the output is sent over to the user's e-mail by a custom procedure (Edit: the output is actually sent over via a download link, so the DB probably writes the CSV file and stores it, but not sure) that I don't know how it was coded (this third-party is not interested in sharing how it works).

Another option is to create snapshots, move those to the new DB once, then update the new DB with the changes from the past day. I'm very worried about this because there are several edge-cases that need to be considered and even more-so because this DB has multiple Primary Keys that change (Transaction 2 is determined to be a reversal of Transaction 1, so they combine 2 into 1).

Is there literally anything that can be done by us? How do companies normally move this much data or keep databases synchronized on a regular basis? Is it a big deal if the process takes hours to finish (for example if we create the outputs in the morning and output them throughout the day to not overload the server)?

Edit: The DB is also not interested in using software that helps with this (Cloudberry for example) or even the built-in Oracle Data Pump

Comment: "*Then the output is sent over to the user's e-mail by a custom procedure*" -  Never heard of anything like this...! The actual data is sent over email for synchronizing, is that what you are saying?

Comment: No, sorry! The output is sent over in a link for download. So my best guess is that the DB writes to a CSV file and stores it, but I really have no clue. Then we retrieve it via the link and move from there

Comment: *"the DBAs are not interested in upgrading their service"*.  Hmmm, it seems like the first thing you need to do is dump those DBAs and get some new ones in.

Comment: *"this DB has multiple Primary Keys that change"*. Primary keys should be immutable. Hmmm, is this new database you're building a **replacement** for the existing one?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what the performance critical path is here. Reading from the source database, writing to the target, passing data across the network, building indexes ... ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying problem seems to be office politics rather than a programming one.

Comment: So where does Postgres come into the picture? Are you trying to replicate from Oracle to Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, replicate from Oracle to Postgres.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I would also love to know. From my testing it seems that it's passing the data through the network, but I can't guarantee that reading isn't slow. Probably not indexes, It's truly a weird situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is there literally anything that can be done by us? How do companies normally move this much data or keep databases synchronized on a regular basis?"

The normal approach would be to use a replication method - Streams or Materialized Views for the more old skool, or Oracle GoldenGate for organisations with the spare cash to pay for the licenses (or a heterogenous data environment which demands it). For a very large amount of data they might choose to do the initial population with Data Pump and use replication to update the target database with deltas.

In other words, just the sort of things you have mentioned in your question. Which points to your real issue: you seem to have a toxic project environment. You won't achieve anything without the active support and engagement of the DBA team. You haven't gone into the details of why the DBAs are not interested in helping. But it wouldn't matter if you had: political questions are well off-topic for StackOverflow.

The point is, what you have is primarily a management issue. Your boss (or your boss's boss) needs to address the situation and unblock the inter-team     channels. It's hard-to-near-impossible to fix a political problem with a technical patch; if you attempt it and don't succeed you don't want to be left holding the baby. So - if only from a career perspective - you should  flag this up quickly, widely and often. At the very least make sure there's something in the risk register.

Comment: I completely agree. The replication to update with deltas is likely the best solution and the issue is the environment, not the coding, unfortunately. My question was really a last effort on my part, and I appreciate the answer!